# Inheritance with Sugar ORM

Tags: android, inheritance, orm, sugarorm

Hi I would like to use Sugar ORM **with inheritance.**

My Classes:

```
  public class Building extends SugarRecord<Building> {

        protected String name;
     }
```

and:

```
 public class Kitchen extends Building{

    int value =1;
 }
```

When i save some kitchens and list them, **i can only query the kitchens AS Kitchens, but cannot AS Buildings.**

Can i solve this somehow or Sugar ORM does not have this feature?

**Logging:**

```
   List<Building> buildingsList = Building.listAll(Building.class);

   for (Building buidling : buildingsList) {
        Log.i("Buildings: ", buidling.toString());
   }

   List<Kitchen> kitchenList = Kitchen.listAll(Kitchen.class);

   for (Kitchen kitchen : kitchenList) {
        Log.i("Kitchens: ", kitchen.toString());
   }
```

**Output:**

```
//Adding Kitchens, 
10-04 13:10:53.212: I/Sugar(12104): Kitchen saved : 1
10-04 13:10:58.058: I/Sugar(12104): Kitchen saved : 2
10-04 13:10:58.455: I/Sugar(12104): Kitchen saved : 3


//Listing Buildings, nothing
10-04 13:11:16.993: D/SQL Log(12104): SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM BUILDING

*NONE*

    //Listing as Kitchens, here they are:
    10-04 13:11:16.993: D/SQL Log(12104): SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM KITCHEN
    10-04 13:11:16.994: I/Kitchens:(12104): com.adamvarhegyi.clanwars.application.model.Kitchen@103ff5bd
    10-04 13:11:16.994: I/Kitchens:(12104): com.adamvarhegyi.clanwars.application.model.Kitchen@354967b2
    10-04 13:11:16.994: I/Kitchens:(12104): com.adamvarhegyi.clanwars.application.model.Kitchen@33859303
```

Comment: If you are open to considering another ORM that can easily handle inheritance, try [JDXA](http://softwaretree.com/v1/products/jdxa/jdxa.html). JDXA can polymorphically fetch objects in a class hierarchy. Also, JDXA does not require you to extend your model classes from any base class.

Answer (score 2):

The table names are the same as the classes, therefore you cannot query a Kitchen in Building or viceversa. I suggest you to use @Table annotation on the Kitchen Class to create a table for Kitchen, and make sure you have a private long id variable for the table (a condition to meet if you use the @Table annotation)
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to inherit a parent class in kitchens? Are you trying to relate kitchens to buildings? If this is the case, you can use sugars built in relationships:

```
public class Building extends SugarRecord<Building> {

    protected String name;
    Kitchens kitchen; 
}
```

Which would allow you to relate a kitchen to a building.

Answer (score 1):

Sugar ORM does not support inheritance for creating a sequence of tables.Extending SugarRecord is the only way to create a table using Sugar ORM.
Kitchen will not be considered as a table by Sqlite and querying it does mean nothing.
Suggestion:Try to make your code suitable to extend SugarRecord or search for other ORMs.